# NullPointerException when using MediaMetadataRetriever from loop with ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I found this example: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/28/query-mp3-information-using-android-supported-function/ for MediaMetadataRetriever, which works fine. But when I try to use it form a loop and add the data to an ArrayList I get this error:

```
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1831)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:674)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:735)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1652)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14003)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4375)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-25 20:20:27.121: E/AndroidRuntime(20692):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the Class with the MediaMetadataRetriever:

```
    public class GenreListing extends Activity {

           ListView listView;
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

            private SongsManager songManager;
            private Utilities utils;            
            private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();       
            private static final String SD_PATH = new String ("/sdcard/");

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.genre_list);

            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.genreOutput);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, songs);        

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            songManager = new SongsManager();
            utils = new Utilities();


                updatePlaylist();

    }   

         private void updatePlaylist() {
                File home = new File(SD_PATH);
                String out = "";
                if (home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length > 0) {
                    for (File file : home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter())) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(file.getPath());

                        String genre = "";
                        //String genre = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUMARTIST);
                        genre = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUMARTIST);   


                    songs.add(genre);
                    mmr.release();

                    }               

            }
    }
```

}

Comment: Add the elements in "updatePlaylist()" to the "adapter" or add them to "songs" before you create the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: If I add the elements in "updatePlaylist()" I get an empty list, if I add updatePlaylist() before the ArrayAdapter it gives me the same error.

Comment: Calling "updatePlaylist()" before the adapter is created will do it. If you do adding the elements to songs after the adapter is created it won't affect your view. Be aware that MediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata could return null, so you potentially add null to your list.

Comment: I've tried, but it just gives me the same error.

Comment: You checked whether genre is null? Try a "if (genre != null)" directly before "songs.add(genre)" if that worked (could result in a completely empty list, but no error should occur!) check whether you used extractMetadata correctly.

Comment: Thank you! That last one solved it. I really appreciate your help, I've been struggling with this for 2 weeks now :)